# Computation of loss is taking very much time on GPU in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, gradient, pytorch, loss-function, loss

I've been trying to implement DCGAN in pytorch. But during training, a single iteration of training loop takes more than 7-8 minutes on GPU on google collab. I can't understand what is wrong in the code. I have been trying many techniques to overcome this issue but nothing seems to be working..

Here's My training loop and it was taking more than 7-8 minutes on a single iteration:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0")

dis = Discriminator().to(device)
Gen = Generator().to(device)

GAN_loss = nn.BCELoss().to(device)

D_optimizer = optim.Adam(dis.parameters(), lr = 0.0002, betas = (0.5, 0.999))
G_optimizer = optim.Adam(Gen.parameters(), lr = 0.0002, betas = (0.5, 0.999))

path = 'gdrive/My Drive/New_data/'
path2 = 'gdrive/My Drive/New_cropped/'

train_data_list = os.listdir(path)
train_data_len = len(train_data_list)

minibatch_size = 64
epochs = 10
G_losses = []
D_losses = []

final_itr = (train_data_len + minibatch_size - 1) // minibatch_size     
data_list = [train_data_list[i * minibatch_size : (i + 1) * minibatch_size] for i in range(final_itr)]

for epoch in range(epochs):
    for count, data in enumerate(data_list):

        train_img = []
        sample_img = []

        for image in data:
            img_train = cv2.imread(path + image).T/255
            img_train = img_train.reshape(1, img_train.shape[0], img_train.shape[1], img_train.shape[2])

            img_sample = cv2.imread(path2 + image,0).T/255
            img_sample = img_sample.reshape(1, 1, img_sample.shape[0], img_sample.shape[1])
            train_img.append(img_train)
            sample_img.append(img_sample)

            assert(img_sample.shape == (1, 1, 144, 144))

            train_image = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.concatenate(train_img, axis = 0)).cuda())
            sample_image = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.concatenate(sample_img, axis = 0)).cuda())
            label = torch.full((train_image.shape[0],), real_label, device=device)

        #Training the discriminator... minimizing -(log(D(x)) - log(1 - D(G(Z))))

        dis.zero_grad()
        Gen.zero_grad()

        G_z = Gen(sample_image.detach())

        disc_real_out = dis(train_image.detach()).view(-1)
        error_real = GAN_loss(disc_real_out, label)
        error_real.backward()

        disc_fake_out = dis(G_z.detach()).view(-1)
        label.fill_(fake_label)
        error_fake = GAN_loss(disc_fake_out, label)
        error_fake.backward()

        total_disc_error = error_real + error_fake
        D_optimizer.step()

        #Training the Generator... maximizing log(D(G(Z))))

        D_G_z = dis(G_z.detach()).view(-1)
        label.fill_(real_label)
        error_gen = GAN_loss(D_G_z, label)
        error_gen.backward()
        G_optimizer.step()

        G_losses.append(error_gen.item())
        D_losses.append(total_disc_error.item())

        print("Discriminator Loss : ", total_disc_error.item(), "\t", "Generator Loss : ", error_gen.item())
```

Comment: Can you show more complete training code, with loop etc.?

Comment: sure I'm updating the code...